# AngularJS date display using moment js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to display current date in my application using moment JavaScript library, I am getting referenceerror message.

I have the moment.js file under my scripts folder and my Bookshow.js file under resource folder.

I also referred to this link but still facing the reference issue - [AngularJs and moment.js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28285059/angularjs-and-moment-js-not-working)

**Error Details**

```
ReferenceError: moment is not defined 
at new <anonymous> (Bookshow.js:2)
at Object.instantiate (angular.js:3501)
at Object.canonymous> (angular.js: 3526)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:3492)
at Object.$get (angular.js:3112) at Object.invoke (angular.js:3492)
at angular.js:3827
at d (angular.js:3193)
at e (angular.js:3223)
at Object.invoke (angular.js:3231)
```

**Code**

```
Bookshow.js

book.service('ApplDate', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter) {

$scope.today = moment();
console.log("today date " + today.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
$scope.applDate = today.format('MM/DD/YYYY');
}]);
```

Comment: It's most likely an import issue. Do you have `import * as moment from 'moment';`?